# The integral $\int\ln(x-\ln(x))~dx$

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, indefinite-integrals, lambert-w

The integral $f(y)=\int_0^y\ln(x-\ln(x))~dx$ is on my mind.

I'm not sure if this has a closed form? Maybe we need to use the lambert-W function to solve this one?

If it cannot be done in closed form, I wonder what a good asymptotic is.

I considered using Taylor series both for solving the integral in closed form and to find a good asymptotic. However $\ln(x)$ (or $\ln(x+1)$) has a limited radius of convergence.

So I'm stuck.

Comment: Mathematica can't find a closed form, which means with 99% probability that it does not exist.

Comment: WolframAlpha ($\approx$ Mathematica) agrees with Mathematica and so does Maple.

Comment: I don't trust computers.

Comment: Lambert W-function can't be applied here since we can't find the expression $W(z)$ such that $z = W(z)e^{W(z)}$

Comment: @NasuSama But we can solve x - ln(x) with the help of the Lambert-W function.

Comment: Asymptotic in what sense?

Comment: It's possible to show that $f(y) \sim y\ln y$ as $y \to \infty$, for instance.

Comment: @AntonioVargas yes but that is just because log is a slowly growing function. You can say that about any similar integral where log is replaced by a slowly growing function.
The estimate is very brutal and imprecise , its like saying $\int f(x) dx$ is about $x f(x)$.
Not so good.

Comment: I was making the explicit claim that $\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{f(y)}{y\ln y} = 1$, and of course this could be improved.  Oh well, that'll show me for trying to be helpful.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I gave you a +1 for that so do not complain ;)
The thing is the comment is just too trivial. At least for me.
Not trying to be arrogant , but being arrogant anyway ;)

Comment: How about $f(y) = y\ln y - y - \tfrac{1}{2}(\ln y)^2 + o(1)$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas better. But did you derive that from the answers already given ? Did you solve the integral or a part of it to conclude this , or did you do something else ?
If you could improve the o(1) that would be nice.

Comment: I didn't work from the answers, no, though I began by writing $\ln(x - \ln x) = \ln x + \ln(1 - (\ln x)/x)$ and integrated the first term explicitly.  It's not too difficult, I'm sure you can take it from here ;)

Comment: @AntonioVargas funny because I originally intended to take the integral of the RHS you wrote but then noticed I could substract a log and get a "shorter" integrand.

Comment: Just a note: I forgot to include the constant order term in my asymptotic there.  It's an integral which I can't evaluate in closed form, approximately equal to 0.164 762 965 412 426.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I think it is better to put the lower bound of integration to be $1$, and assume $y>0$ so that we get a definite integral:
$$f(y)=\int_1^y\ln(x-\ln(x))dx$$
Substituting $x = e^z$ we get:
$$\begin{array}{ll}f(y) & =\int_0^{\ln y}\ln(e^z-z)e^zdz\\&=\int_0^{\ln y}\ln(e^z-z)(e^z-1)dz+\int_0^{\ln y}\ln(e^z-z)dz\end{array}$$
Notice that the integral on the left is of the form $\int g(f(z))f'(z)dz=G(f(z))$, where $G$ is a primitive of $g$. Thus with $g(z)=\ln(z)$ and $f(z)=e^z-z$ we get:
$$\begin{array}{ll}f(y) & =\bigg[ (e^z-z)\ln(e^z-z) - (e^z-z)\bigg]_0^{\ln y}+\int_0^{\ln y}\ln(e^z-z)dz\\&=(y-\ln y)[\ln(y-\ln y)-1]+1+\int_0^{\ln y}\ln(e^z-z)dz\end{array}$$
We are left with the problem of computing the integral:
$$h(y)=\int_0^{\ln y}\ln(e^z-z)dz.$$
(**Edit:** I deleted what followed here in my old answer, because it was false. I haven't found a solution yet, but I propose the following way to proceed.)

Define
$$H(y,a) = \int_0^{\ln(y)}(e^z - z)^adz,$$
then $h(y) = \partial_aH(y,0)$, so the original question is reduced to finding a closed form for $H$ (or showing that it doesn't exist), which looks more manageable.

One possible way to proceed from here could be as follows: use the (generalized) binomial theorem to write
$$(e^z-z)^a = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{a}{k}e^{(a-k)z}z^k.$$
If we can exchange somehow the integral with the sum (**and there's some work to do**), then we would get
$$H(y,a) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{a}{k}\int_0^{\ln(y)}e^{(a-k)z}z^kdz.$$
We can now do the integral integrating by parts. Let
$$s_k = \int_0^{\ln(y)}e^{(a-k)z}z^kdz.$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
s_0 = & \int_0^{\ln(y)}e^{az}dz = \frac{y^a-1}{a}\\
s_{k>0} = & \left[\frac{e^{(a-k)z}}{a-k}z^k\right]_0^{\ln(y)} - \int_0^{\ln(y)}\frac{e^{(a-k)z}}{a-k}kz^{k-1}dz\\
= & \frac{y^{a-k}}{a-k}\ln(y)^k - \frac{k}{a-k}s_{k-1}.
\end{align}$$
Now this looks somewhat ugly, but considering instead the whole term $t_k = (-1)^k\binom{a}{k}s_k$ and using $\binom{a}{k} = \tfrac{a-k}{k}\binom{a}{k-1}$, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
t_0 = & \frac{y^{a-1}}{a}\\
t_{k>0} = & \binom{a}{k-1}\frac{y^{a-k}\ln(y)^k}{k} + t_{k-1}.
\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$$t_k = \frac{y^a-1}{a} + \sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^i\binom{a}{i-1}\frac{y^{a-i}\ln(y)^i}{i}$$

Now we would like to sum over all $t_k$, and then try to differentiate the resulting expression. This again looks like an ugly beast (a priori, it looks as if it shouldn't converge, so I'm not really sure this approach will work). I will try to work on this in the next few days if I find the time, meanwhile any help, comments, hints, partial solutions or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be appropriate to use Lambert-W now ?? Since after the final integral written,I see $e^z-z$ and I believe that can be solved with the Lambert-W. Maybe a substitution. Or contour.

Comment: @mick I am not familiar with the $W$ function. I have tried to do it using the Feynman trick and I think I've got something, but you should check it is correct.

Comment: The Feynman trick ? From the physicist ?

Comment: Did you check your answer numerically?  I think I typed it in correctly but the expression you got for $I'(0)$ doesn't seem to match the numerical evaluation of the integral $h(y)$.

Comment: @mick Yes, take a look at this: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf

Comment: @AntonioVargas As I said, it is possible I made some error somewhere. Maybe I will check everything again in the near future, but not now.

Answer (score 1):

Maple seems to only have a difficulty with $$\int_0^1\ln(x-\ln x) dx = 0.3224577\ldots =: C$$
The taylor series about $y=1$ is the given by
$$I(y+1) = C + \frac16 y^3 - \frac1{12} y^4 + \frac1{40} y^5 - \frac1{180} y^6 + \mathcal O(y^7)$$
[image: Plot of $I(y)$ for $y \in [0,5]$]

Comment: Thanks but I want better approximations.

Comment: If you want one, tell me how many coefficients you want ;) $y=1$ seems a good origin point when looking at the plot.

Comment: Cf. [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28x-ln%28x%29%29]